# I was attempting a problem online need assist as I am unable pass hidden test cases. Please point out fault in my code

Tags: c++, arrays

**Problem**

---

Finally, progress reached the Madoka family and she decided to play with her little sister in the sensational game Space Arrays.

The rules of the game are as follows:

- Initially, a sequence a1,a2,…,aN is given.
- The players alternate turns.
- In each turn, the current player must choose an index i and increment ai, i.e. change ai to ai+1.
- Afterwards, if there is no permutation p1,p2,…,pN of the integers 1
  through N such that ai≤pi holds for each valid i, the current player
  loses.
- Otherwise, the game continues with the next turn.

Madoka is asking you to help her ― tell her if the first player (the player that plays in the first turn) or second player wins this game if both play optimally.

---

**Input**

- The first line of the input contains a single integer T denoting the
  number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows.
- The first line of each test case contains a single integer N.
- The second line contains N space-separated integers a1,a2,…,aN.

---

**Output**

For each test case, print a single line containing the string "First" if the first player wins or "Second" if the second player wins (without quotes).

---

**Constraints**

- 1≤T≤2⋅10^4
- 1≤N≤2⋅10^5
- The sum of N over all test cases doesn't exceed 2⋅10^5
- 1≤ai≤N for each valid i

---

**Subtasks**

**Subtask #1 (100 points):** Original constraints

---

**Example Input**

```
4
4
1 2 3 3
4
1 1 3 3
5
1 2 2 1 5
3
2 2 3
```

---

**Example Output**

```
First
Second
Second
Second
```

---

**Explanation**

**Example case 1:**

- If the first player increases the fourth element, the resulting sequence is (1,2,3,4).The second player loses after increasing any of the elements.
- If the first player increases the second element, the resulting
  sequence is (1,3,3,3) ,and he loses because there is no valid
  permutation. For example if p=(2,1,4,3), the second element of a is
  greater than the second element of p.

---

### Time Limit : 1 Secs
Source limit : 50000 byte

**Here is my code**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define lli long long int

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    lli t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--){
        lli n;
        cin >> n;
        int arr;
         int  arrSum = 0;
        for(lli i=0; i<n ;i++){
            cin >> arr;
            arrSum += arr;
        }

        
        lli turn = 0;
       lli sum = (n*(n+1))/2;
        turn = sum-arrSum;
        if(turn < 0){
            turn = 0;
        }
        if(turn%2 == 1){
            cout << "First" << endl;
        }
        else{
            cout << "Second" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The main thing about online judge or competition sites (besides teaching extremely bad habits) seems to be mostly about *trickery*. The two most common "tricks" is to either find out a formula or equation to a problem, so one doesn't have to use a loop to calculate a value; And to cache results of previous calculations (so-called *dynamic programming*).

Comment: Yeah there is some problem with sum but I am not able to finding solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your algorithm you don't check if first player initially loses without making a turn but the sum is lower than `n*(n+1)/2`, e.g. for input

```
1
5
1 1 2 5 5
```

The sum is 13.

```
5 * (5 + 1) / 2 - (1 + 1 + 2 + 5 + 5) == 1
```

But first player can't do anything and has lost before the first turn. Ssecond player wins.

Actual output from your code: `First`.

Expected output: `Second`

Another example is

```
1
5
1 1 4 4 4
```

with

```
5 * (5 + 1) / 2 - (1 + 1 + 4 + 4 + 4) == 1
```

In both cases your code returns that first player wins but actually second player wins without the game even starting.

Comment: I have tried all three input my output is second  in all cases Idk what are you trying to explain. can you explain more?

Comment: @codeghostslayer https://wandbox.org/permlink/z5I1zwG315NYv9bL Your actual output is `first`. Expected output is `second`.